# Unable to get jQuery to .css("display", "block") when clicking on a link

Tags: jquery, html, css

I am trying to get jQuery to display CSS properties when a href link is clicked on.

I have tested the CSS properties and when setting the display to "block" (on the style sheet) they work as you would imagine, however, when I set the initial CSS display to "none" and try to have jQuery change this to block when the link has been clicked on - nothing happens.

I am using .css("display", "block") and can see no reason why this would not work so any advice would be great!

```
<style type="text/css">

   #contactOuter {
   position: fixed;
   height:100%;
   width: 100%;
   background: rgba(10, 10, 10, 0.5);
   z-index: 1010;
   display: none;
 }

</style>


<html>

<a href="" id="contactLink">Contact Us</a>

</html>


<script type="text/javascript">

$("#contactLink").click(function(){
    $("#contactOuter").css("display", "block");
});

</script>
```

Comment: put the jquery code AFTER the html code and it will work or use document.ready

Comment: it is placed after the html code, sorry its just the way I have laid the question out on here.

Comment: you need to provide us the exact same way and same code ... changing the code will change the behavior .. and actuallythere is no element `#contactOuter` in the code

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your code works! Its just that the page is refreshing when you click on the anchor link. Use `javascript:void(0);` on href attribute

```
<a href="javascript:void(0);" id="contactLink">Contact Us</a>

<div id="contactOuter">Hello</div>
```

Also the best practice is wrap the Js into `$(document).ready(function{ //code here });`

```
$(document).ready(function() {
  $("#contactLink").click(function() {
    $("#contactOuter").css("display", "block");
  });
});
```

Hope this helps.

Answer (score 0):

Like other says. First you should learn how to structure your html code first with `html,head,body` and understanding the workflow of the page. It reads from top to bottom.
Also you need to include the jquery.js first...

```
<html>
<head>
<style type="text/css">

   #contactOuter {
   position: fixed;
   height:100%;
   width: 100%;
   background: rgba(10, 10, 10, 0.5);
   z-index: 1010;
   display: none;
 }

</style>
</head>
<body>
<a href="" id="contactLink">Contact Us</a>

<script>

$("#contactLink").click(function(){
    $("#contactOuter").css("display", "block");
});

</script>

</body>
</html>
```

Answer (score 0):

The correct way to do this is to use show and hide:

```
$("#contactLink").click(function(){
    $("#contactOuter").show();
});
```

An alternate way is to use the jQuery css method:

```
$("#contactLink").click(function(){
$("#id").css("display", "block");
});
```